# Weekly Twice - One word

Tags: word-choice

Is there any single word which can substitute "weekly twice" or "twice in a week"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word is [*twice-weekly*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/twice-weekly) with [*semi-weekly*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/semi-weekly) as a synonym and [*semiweekly*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/semiweekly) as an alternative spelling.

Comment: **Biweekly** generally means "every two weeks", but sometimes may be used as "twice a week".

Comment: Yes, *biweekly* and *bimonthly* are perpetual sources of confusion.

Comment: That's why we have *fortnightly*. We probably don't need a single unambiguous word for "twice a week", because there aren't that many things that happen that often.

Comment: Twice a week is hard because a week has an odd number of days :-)