# What's the term for something that happens twice a week?

Tags: single-word-requests

"Biweekly" means every two weeks.
What's the term for something that happens twice a week?

> We need to have _______ meetings until this crisis is over.

Comment: You may have had [a related question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50658/are-there-any-words-i-can-use-to-disambiguate-biweekly) offered to you when you posted this question. It appears to be the same as this one. What is different here?

Comment: @AndrewLeach thanks - that question did not show up in the "related questions"

Comment: @Andrew - There are actually [a few questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=biweekly) on the site that discuss *biweekly*. It seems like one gets asked biannually.

Comment: The question promoted as a duplicate does not include the single word answer: "twice-weekly". Another question, [Weekly Twice - One word](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45351/weekly-twice-one-word), does promote that answer. All the bi-weekly questions should be consolidated to sort out the mess.